# Using string.prototype with click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an extension method named `.Switch()` like this:

```
    String.prototype.Switch = function (p) {
        console.log(this); // should log $obj
    };

    var $obj = $("div");
    $("a", $obj).click(function (e) {
        $obj.Switch(0);
    });
```

HTML

```
 <div>
   <a href="#">Link</a>
 </div>
```

And I'm getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Can someone show me how this is done?

Comment: `$obj` is not a string.

Comment: Would I do `Object.prototype`?

Comment: I think it should be fine. However note that `$obj` here is actual a jQuery object.

Comment: Object, String, are different "types"

Comment: I tried and get the same error in `jquery.js`

Comment: Using `Object.prototype` seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/yLbmxr5b/ (open the console window to see the result, the jQuery object is actually logged there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$obj` is a jQuery object, not a string. If you want to add functions to it, you should do so in this way:

```
jQuery.fn.Switch = function (p) {
     console.log(this); // should log $obj
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The error your getting is because you are extending the String Object by adding a Switch function to the prototype. However, the function your calling Switch on is a JQuery Object. 
So If we Modify your example:

```
String.prototype.Switch = function (p) {
    console.log(p); // should log input
};

var testStr = 'hello'; // create a new instance of String Object

testStr.Switch(5); // will log 5
```

So similarly if you declare the function on the prototype of the JQuery object you will be able to call that function from all instances of the JQuery Object.

Comment: I want to log `$obj`, not `p`, like in my example.

Comment: you could replace p for this, and it would log the instance that invokes that function. However, the point was more about declaring the function on the prototype of the correct type of object. The answer below is what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`var $obj = $("div");` is a jQuery object. You could do `var $obj = $("div").text();` which would call `Switch` with a string instead of an object.

You need to do `$.prototype.Switch` to log the object.